# MikTex 2.9 64-bit not loading sans serif font for moderncv

Tags: fonts, miktex, moderncv, sans-serif, roman

I just got a new computer and installed MikTex 2.9 for Windows7 64-bit.

When I compiled my resume for the first time (`moderncv`, theme `casual`), it compiled in roman vs. sans serif fonts. I did not specify the `roman` argument, so the document should default to sans serif fonts.

Why can't I get sans serif fonts? I hate roman.

Example of file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letter]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[green]{casual}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.835]{geometry}

\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}  

\firstname{Fname}
\familyname{Lnmae}

\address{123 Main St.}{city, state 00000}
\mobile{999 999 9999}

\email{person@email.com}

\nopagenumbers{} 
\hyphenpenalty=100000

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\vspace{-.5in}

\section{Objective}
\cvline{}{Hire Me!}

\section{Experience}

\cventry{Summer 2009}{Trading Post Manager}{Company Name}{Somewhere, NC}{}{Implemented ECR system to manage and report inventory of 350+ items; managed daily operations.}

\end{document}
```

Excerpt from `\listfiles`:

```
*File List*
moderncv.cls    2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document c
lass
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    [...]
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 lmodern.sty    2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
    [...]
  ot1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
  omllmm.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omslmsy.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
 omxlmex.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is the `lmodern` package installed? It might be helpful if you include `\listfiles` at the beginning of your document, recompile, and add the list of files printed in your .log file to your question here by clicking [edit].

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I added the list of files; it appears that the lmodern package is in use.

Comment: As requested, MWE.

Comment: @Xavier While it is a good idea to clean up questions and especially the code, in my opinion you went too far in this case – not to mention, that you in your answer refer to code, which you deleted now. Instead you should have shown a good MWE in your answer (there’s a typo now, so you have to edit anyway). Also the output of `\listfiles` was asked in a comment above. I just made a rollback.

Comment: @Xavier: Additional link: [When is it (and isn't) acceptable to edit?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit).

Comment: @Speravir Sorry if I unintentionally broke any rule, though I can't figure out which in your link. I still believe the "MWE" shown is not only far from minimal, but on top shows deprecated code and should therefore be edited. For the listing, one can't edit the MWE without changing the listing, and the only relevant part of the listing is anyway that `lmodern.sty` was correctly loaded, as mentioned in meryl's comment. Just my opinion, I am still new to tex.sx :)

Comment: “Unacceptable. To change the original meaning". I already said you have the chance to show a good MWE in your answer. There you can do, what most others do: Take the original code and change it according to, how it should be in your eyes. Regarding the `\listfiles`: I may be wrong, but I think it is usually not shortened, but of course, one really who knows, what is necessary and what not, could do it.

Comment: @Speravir Since Xavier is the author of the package in question and he also fixed the irrelevant parts of the code I think it's not that dramatic in this very specific problem.

Comment: Yay thanks for asking the question and the answer! JUst set up a new install of MikTex as well and was baffled when my CV's font changed after recompiling.

Answer (score 9):

The `sans` class option, for sans serif fonts, need to be specified explicitly when loading `moderncv` since version 0.15, i.e.

```
\documenclass[sans]{moderncv}
```

Note also that `\moderncvtheme` is deprecated, in favor of `\moderncvstyle` and `\moderncvcolor`, and that `\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}` is not required anymore.

Your MWE would then look like

```
\documentclass[sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}                

\firstname{Fname}
\familyname{Lname}    
\address{123 Main St.}{City, State 00000}{Country}
\mobile{999 999 9999}
\email{person@email.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Objective}
\cvline{}{Hire Me!}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The sans option does the trick. Surprised that this JUST starting being a problem for me if that change has been in effect since 0.15.

Comment: @meryl Well, it depends what distribution you use and how frequently it updates packages. I had to go check my commits to find out when the behavior changed :)